# How should we deal with posts that complain about the plot/characters/author?

Tags: discussion

For example:
**Q** Why did Alice fall in love with Bob?
**A** The author sucks, and the whole plot is stupid.

What should we do with such posts? You must be wondering why do I even ask this question?

That's because "plot hole" can be a legitimate answer to some questions. We can complain all we like about how something is illogical, but on a Q&A site, if "plot hole" is the answer to the question, then we have to accept it. Thus, the above post can be improved by editing out the rant.

Should we edit it/get it edited or flag it like on other SE sites?

Note: I have delibarately avoided giving examples for obvious reasons, but you can easily figure out what I am referring to from the main site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such questions should be closed. Answers should be downvoted, and maybe deleted.

If you can edit the post to improve it, do so. If you cannot , leave a comment for the author to do it, and if he fails to do so, flag or vote to delete it.

Posts like those aren't useful, there's a huge difference between "it's a plot hole" and "the author sucks".

Comment: ...and if it's just a snarky answer to a *legitimate* question, you should flag for moderator attention.